# Check if a directory contains a file with a given extension

Tags: python, file-exists

I need to check the current directory and see if a file with an extension exists. My setup will (usually) only have one file with this extension. I need to check if that file exists, and if it does, run a command.

However, it runs the `else` multiple times because there are multiple files with alternate extensions. It must only run the `else` if the file does not exist, not once for every other file. My code sample is below.

---

The directory is structured like so:

```
dir_________________________________________
    \            \            \            \     
 file.false    file.false    file.true    file.false
```

When I run:

```
import os
for File in os.listdir("."):
    if File.endswith(".true"):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

The output is:

```
false
false
true
false
```

The issue with this is if I replaced `print("false")` with something useful, it will run it multiple times.

**Edit:** I asked this question 2 years ago, and it's still seeing very mild activity, therefore, I'd like to leave this here for other people: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the `else` block of the `for`:

```
for fname in os.listdir('.'):
    if fname.endswith('.true'):
        # do stuff on the file
        break
else:
    # do stuff if a file .true doesn't exist.
```

The `else` attached to a `for` will be run whenever the `break` inside the loop is *not* executed. If you think a `for` loop as a way to search something, then `break` tells whether you have found that something. The `else` is run when you didn't found what you were searching for.

Alternatively:

```
if not any(fname.endswith('.true') for fname in os.listdir('.')):
    # do stuff if a file .true doesn't exist
```

---

Moreover you could use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) module instead of `listdir`:

```
import glob
# stuff
if not glob.glob('*.true')`:
    # do stuff if no file ending in .true exists
```

Comment: with the new pathlib library, you can change glob to `if not list(pathlib.Path(".").rglob("*.true"))`

Answer (score 22):

If you only want to check that any file ends with a particular extension, use `any`.

```
import os
if any(File.endswith(".true") for File in os.listdir(".")):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module to look for exactly the files that you're interested in:

```
import glob

fileList = glob.glob("*.true")
for trueFile in fileList:
    doSomethingWithFile(trueFile)
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @bgporter's solution, you could also use *Path* to do something similar:

```
from pathlib import Path
cwd = Path.cwd()
for path in cwd.glob("*.true"):
   print("true")
   DoSomething(path)
```

Comment: do you mean `from pathlib import Path` by import Path?

Comment: Yes that's right, just corrected that, thanks for spotting that. @SardarFaisal

Answer (score 0):

Alternative if you want to use the same logic you can try to use a flag that turns on only if the file does not exist. Then use an if to run the not exist script.

```py
import os 

for File in os.listdir("."): 
    if File.endswith(".true"):
        print("true") 
    else:
      flag=True
 
if flag:
  # -your code-
```

Comment: This is a useful answer because a reader may learn to use this technique in other circumstances. It also would work in all languages. A disadvantage is that it continues to run the loop, even if `flag` has already been found. One might rectify this with a `break` after setting the flag.

Comment: As another note, `flag` ought to be initialized. I don't remember Python's treatment of uninitialized values, but even if it treats them falsey, it is best to initialize for clarity.